# Does Django OneToOneField needs to be unique?

Tags: django, model, one-to-one

I get a "column template_id is not unique" error, now let me explain.
I have a template model and a player version of it.

Template:

```
class FarmTemplate(models.Model):
    """Template of the "Farm" building"""

    name = models.CharField(max_length=23)
    flavor = models.TextField()
    resource = models.CharField(max_length=23)
    version = models.FloatField(unique=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

My User model:

```
class Farm(models.Model):
    """Keeps track of Townhall"""

    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    template = models.OneToOneField(FarmTemplate)
    level = models.IntegerField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "User: %s, Farm level: %s" % (self.user, self.level)
```

When I create my first object everything goes right, however, when I create a second it tells me the OneToOneField isnt unique (which is correct since it uses the same template.
But I have no clue why this needs to be unique.. 
Can someone please explain where I went wrong?

Comment: Hmm in the Stackoverflow the word template becomes blue and could be some build in option? I dont know if this also is the case within python? If so, that might explain some (doesnt get a special color in geany)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

OnetoOne means each tuple is unique. I think you should use ForeignKey:

```
class Farm(models.Model):
"""Keeps track of Townhall"""

user = models.ForeignKey(User)
template = models.ForeignKey(FarmTemplate)
level = models.IntegerField()

def __unicode__(self):
    return "User: %s, Farm level: %s" % (self.user, self.level)
```

Comment: Okay, thanks, i was kinda sure it had to do with the OneToOneField, just not sure why

Answer (score 3):

Just to add a reason to the answer of Alvaro (since you say in your comment you don't understand why):

Take this as an example: A --> B (A = source, B = target)

If you are haveing a one-to-one relation, it implies that if you have one source A, you have a relation to one specific target B (otherwise ot would be one-to-many). For target B, the only related source element can be A, since it is allowed to relate just to one (one-to-one), otherwise it would be many-to-one.

A ForeignKey allows to refer many objets to one related object