# Editing a Row using Django Forms

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I wanted to edit a row in Django 1.9 using Django forms:

So what I did is

For the get request I initialized the form instance (views.py)

```
def get(self, request):
    myModel = model.myModel.objects.get(user=request.user)
    form_instance = MyForm(initial=myModel.__dict__)
    return render(request, 'mytemplate.html', {'form': form_instance} )

def post(self, request):
    form_instance = MyForm(request.POST)
    if form_instance.is_valid():
        form_instance.save()
        return redirect('..')
    return render(request, 'mytemplate.html', {'form': form_instance} )
```

This is my models.py

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Booth = models.OneToOneField(BoothLocation)
class BoothLocation(models.Model):
    LocationID = models.CharField(max_length = 25)
```

and I have a forms.py

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ('Booth')
        labels = {'Booth':_('Booth Chosen')}
```

My problem is that my model have a one to one field, therefore whenever I execute

```
form_instance = MyForm(request.POST)
```

it will return an error stating that the onetoonefield must be unique, but I'm just updating it. Is there a way to override this validation?

And by the way, the field really needs to be one on one.

Comment: yup it is, just a typo. :) But the question remains the same. :)

Comment: That may should help you. Switch to ForeignKey http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20909039/does-django-onetoonefield-needs-to-be-unique

Comment: Thank you @user2853437. But the problem is it really needs to be one to one and I just need to edit it.

Comment: Post your full view

Comment: …and the model and the form!

Comment: @KlausD. edited. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing this bit wrong

```
form_instance = MyForm(initial=myModel.__dict__)
```

it should be

```
form_instance = MyForm(instance=myModel)
```

Oops, forgot to add, in order to handle the situation where the form validation fails, your post meethod might need something like this:

```
form_instance = MyForm(request.POST, instance=myModel)
```

you would need to fetch the instance again. As a side note, your code can be greatly simplified by combining your two functions into one and adding if else inside it

```
if request.method == 'POST':

else:
```

Comment: You're a life saver. :) Thank you.

Comment: Glad to have helped

Comment: Just a note. Also need to change
form_instance = MyForm(request.POST) to
form_instance = MyForm(request.POST, instance=MyModel)