# How to solve "field must be unique" in django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am creating an app with vue and django but struggle with getting information from serializer. my models look like this:

models.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Order(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255) 
    posted_by = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Offer(models.Model):
    order_related = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='offers')
    author = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

serializers.py:

```
class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ("user",)


class OfferSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    author = ProfileSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = Offer
        fields = ("id", "order_related", 
                  "author", 
         )


class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    posted_by = ProfileSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ("id",  "posted_by", "name")
```

views.py:

```
class OfferView(ListModelMixin, GenericAPIView, CreateModelMixin):

    queryset = Offer.objects.all()
    serializer_class = OfferSerializer 

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.create(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

when i send info to this view:

```
     const formData = {
      order_related: this.$route.params.order_id,
      author: {user: localStorage.getItem("user")},
    } 
    
        axios  
    .post("api/v1/offers/", formData)
```

i get error:

```
{"user":["Values of field must be unique."]}
```

Is there any way to override this?

P.S. To write AbstactUser model etc. - not a way

To send another request in order to get by id for detailed info is also not the best

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does Django OneToOneField needs to be unique?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20909039/does-django-onetoonefield-needs-to-be-unique)

Comment: does this mean that the only way is to change OneToOne to FK? 

My models are created simultaneously thanks to signals. OneToOne Field is the way to guarantee that profile_id = user_id. So switching to FK does not fit my interests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

- views.py

```py
from rest_framework.exceptions import ValidationError
from rest_framework.response import Response

class OfferView(ListModelMixin, GenericAPIView):
    queryset = Offer.objects.all()
    serializer_class = OfferSerializer 

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        data = request.data
        order_id = data.get('order_related')
        user_id = data.get('author', {}).get('user')
        try:
            order_id = int(order_id)
            user_id = int(user_id)
        except (TypeError, ValueError):
            raise ValidationError(f'Invalid post data: {order_id=};{user_id=}')
        profile = Profile.objects.get(user_id=user_id)
        order = Order.objects.get(id=order_id)
        obj = self.queryset.create(order_related=order, author=profile)
        return Response(self.serializer_class(obj).data)
```

Comment: getting "Invalid post data"

Answer (score 0):

Profile class having only 1 OneToOneField looks redundant.

You can simply work on User class.

Comment: But if I work on user class, I must have been created my own one, not standart. I can't extend a standart one if I'm not mistaken

Comment: Makesure order_id and localStorage.getItem("user") both be integer.

Comment: i’ve made sure but still not working